# Can I branch from a laundry circuit for an outside outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

In my laundry room, I have a single 120v outlet that the washing machine plugs into.  It seem that no other outlet runs off this 20 amp circuit.  Given that I had to re-label all the circuit breakers in the home I can say this with 95% confidence.  Even if I am incorrect, at most there is another outlet or 2 connected to this circuit well below capacity.

So I would like to connect this outlet to one I run outside.  This would mean cutting into the drywall, navigating around plumbing, and going through concrete block to get there.  Obviously I would then install a GFCI in a waterproof box (which I have done before).

Comment: Questions must be specific. I've removed the "how do I wire things?" portion of your question. Feel free to post additional detailed questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You can't do that, legally.

(Assuming USA / NEC - location says Florida on profile)

The laundry room circuit is, by code [ 210.11(c)(3) ], only for the laundry room. So you can't do that, you'll need to start from another circuit or run a new circuit from the panel. That circuit can have as many outlets as you like *in the laundry area*, but it's *only* for that area.

Other than that hurdle:

For an outside circuit, it is far better to put the GFCI protection inside, not out in the weather. Even "weatherproof" GFCIs fail much faster out in the weather than a GFCI in the nice dry interior of the house. Label the outside one as "GFCI protected" (required by code), and be clever and also mention where the GFCI for it is located, in the house (not required by code, but *a good idea.*)

As for running cable, or wire in conduit, once you get over doing drywall repair and drilling holes in perfectly good walls, it's moderately straightforward. Since you can't use the laundry room circuit as a starting point, you can pick a section of wall without plumbing in it to avoid that particular problem. Concrete block will require a long masonry bit and suitable drill (the drill can be rented, usually the bit has to be purchased, if you don't have a suitable drill and don't want to buy one.)

Comment: A rotary hammer makes drilling through a block wall _easier_, but it's not mandatory to use one to do so. Of course, if the particular portion you've chosen to drill through happens to be filled with concrete, it makes is _much_ easier, but still not mandatory. You can use a masonry bit in a regular drill and get there eventually. Just use patience and _lots_ of it.

Comment: I limited my drill recommendation to "suitable." That's in the eye of the beholder, as some folks are more patient, and others less so. And that's fine.  You can do it with a star drill and a hammer, or a diamond core drill, or a LASER, if you can borrow Dr. Evil's shark for a minute.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't intended to be a complaint, but a note to the OP that renting/buying a hammer drill wasn't required to do this if he has enough patience... You already had my +1

Comment: Thank you for all your info.  Given my current solution (run a extension cord out the laundry room window) when needed.  It might be a good idea to replace the existing receptacle with a GFI.

Comment: Under current code (though perhaps not when yours was built) it should be a GFCI anyway.

Comment: @Ecnerwal again, thank you.  This house was flipped about 6 years a go and those flippers did a lot of goofy stuff.

Comment: For drilling through block, a hammer drill and large bit does the trick.  Not much patience is needed but some in and out to clear the hole of the dust.